# How do i replace multiple occurences of multiple values in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a column within a `data.frame` with multiple occurrences of each of its unique values which i need to replace with different values. How can I achieve this?

I created a factor of the unique values and tried replacing each element by looping over the factor levels using the `gsub` function

```
nf <- factor(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
let <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

dat <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)

dat <- for (i in levels(nf)){
gsub(i,let[i], dat
}
```

I expected an output of :

```
"a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d" "d" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e" "f" "f" "f" "f" "f" "f"
```

but instead I get: `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just after

```
let[dat]
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d" "d" "e" "e" "e" "e" "e" "f" "f" "f" "f"
#[20] "f" "f"
```

Or if you prefer a `factor`

```
factor(dat, labels = let)
```

Comment: @Gboyega.A If this answers your question please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for future SO users to identify relevant questions. It also awards a small reputation bonus to both the original poster and answerer.